# Django foreign key as dropdown choice with optgroups

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have following django models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Company(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'Title'), max_length=128)

class Profile(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name='Company')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='User', null=True, blank=True)

class ServiceCategory(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    title = models.CharField(_(u'Title'), max_length=64)

class Service(BaseModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCategory)
    title = models.CharField(_(u'Title'), max_length=64)
```

As you can see, each ServiceCategory has Company foreign key. Company is also used to group Users (each User have one2one relation to the Profile, where Company is foreign key for Profile.

Anyway, I need a form field with dropdown which will show all available services in company grouped (using optgroup) by categories (categories are not selectable), like:

**Category1**

- Service1
- Service2
- Service3

**Category2**

- Service4
- Service5

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: try posting your company ad profile model as well

Answer (score -2, accepted):

DJ form does support optgroup, however you need to provide the form field with a custom formatted choice list.

```
# in the form init
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # you need to manual format for queryset to be in this format
    service_choices = (
     ('Cat1', (
       ('service1_id', 'Service1'),
       ('service2_id', 'Service2'),
     ),
     ('Cat2', (
       ('service3_id', 'Service3'),
       ('service4_id', 'Service4'),
     ),
    )

self.fields['your_service_field'].choices = service_choices
```

Comment: I knew that. I was asking for help in making queryset in this format